# Retrieving Bookmarks from Vivaldi web browser

Tags: dual-boot, bookmarks

How to retrieve bookmarks from Vivaldi web browser while my Ubuntu partition is not booting properly?

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. The Ubuntu partition is not booting properly and I have installed Disk-Internals-Research to load the Ubuntu files form Windows. But the problem is I don't know where to look for the bookmarks in Ubuntu and is it possible to have them in my Vivaldi browser in Windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 This question is unique and even not found yet on other SE sites to this date. Despite being left unanswered for almost one year, I posted an answer at below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivaldi stores the bookmarks in the profile folder, so look for that folder.

In Vivaldi web browser:

- Go to **Main Menu > Help > About**
- A new tab will open the internal page `vivaldi://about`
- In the page, the last line will show similar to the following line:

  ```
  Profile Path:   /home/USERNAME/.config/vivaldi/Default
  ```

  where by `USERNAME` is user name in Ubuntu, or path may be different at all.
- Then, open a file manager and go to the profile path
- Finally, user can either copy the entire folder or just the `Bookmarks` file

The profile path shown at above is applicable to Ubuntu and official flavours. If user is running different systems, user may need to repeat above steps at least *twice*, one time for the Vivaldi profile folder in Ubuntu *and* one more time for another system.

Take note of the profile paths, in order to follow the next instruction.

### Import bookmarks from Vivaldi to Vivaldi

The direct way to import bookmarks:

- First, copy the `Bookmarks` file in *old* profile folder (Ubuntu) to overwrite `Bookmarks` file in *new* profile folder (another system)
- Then, restart Vivaldi
- Finally, the *old* bookmarks will be available in Vivaldi

Else, user may try **File > Import Bookmarks... > From Vivaldi**. Although, running the feature will only detect current profile folder itself and the import folder is not selectable for 'Vivaldi' option, which is somewhat odd.

For Vivaldi on working systems, user can retrieve bookmarks from **File > Export Bookmarks...** and save bookmarks in HTML file format. Later, user can select **Import Bookmarks... > From Bookmarks HTML file - Choose a file...** to restore the saved bookmarks instead of the former.

### View bookmarks without import

The Vivaldi bookmarks file is actually a plain text in JSON format, albeit without any file extension. You can view the bookmarks in any text editor or Vivaldi web browser itself (screenshot: left).

[image: Read the bookmarks file in Vivaldi and Firefox]

Another way is to rename the file from `Bookmarks` to `Bookmarks.json`. Then, open in JSON viewer or a recent Firefox web browser to view JSON in pretty format (screenshot: right).

**Remarks**: This answer intends to be generic and comprehensive. Although this answer does not specifically explain how to import bookmarks for Ubuntu-Windows environment, the instructions are generic and relevant for single or dual-boot environment regardless.